# Does there exist an approximate formula which can calculate the sum of the reciprocal of squarefree number which have an even number of prime factors?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Example :

The sum of the reciprocal of the squarefree numbers $\text{Se}(X)$ with an even number $2k$ of prime factors, where $k>0$

For $k$ less than $49$:

$\text{Se}(49)=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{14}+\frac{1}{22}+\frac{1}{26}+\frac{1}{34}+\frac{1}{38}+\frac{1}{46}+\frac{1}{15}+\frac{1}{21}+\frac{1}{33}+\frac{1}{39}+\frac{1}{35} = \frac{77 \ 890 \ 556}{111 \ 546 \ 435}$

I want an approximate formula for $\text{Se}(X)$.

Comment: Just to clarify : Is $X$ the limit for the numbers which are to be summed up ?

Comment: Is 2/46 a typo? If not explain it.

Comment: Fixed MathJax, assuming the $2/46$ was a typo. OP, welcome to MSE! This question may not be up to the site standards for questions... is there any context we should know about? Is there anything you've attempted to do?

Comment: 2/46 is a typo.

Comment: I want the sum of the reciprocal of all the squarefree numbers with an even number of prime factors where the denominators are all less than or equal to X.

Comment: You've omitted the number $1$ which seems to meet the criteria, so perhaps you should clarify your definition.

Comment: I see what you mean. I overlooked that 1 has 0 primefactors and 0 is even.

Comment: would rewriting as $\frac12\left ( \prod (1+1/p)+\prod(1-1/p)\right )$ help?

Comment: Hint: since $\sum_{n\le x} \frac{\mu^2(n)}n \sim \frac6{\pi^2}\log x$, we might imagine that restricting to those with an even number of prime factors would yield $\sim \frac3{\pi^2}\log x$. To prove this, write the desired sum as $$\frac12\biggl( \sum_{n\le x} \frac{\mu^2(n)}n + \sum_{n\le x} \frac{\mu^2(n)(-1)^{\omega(n)}}n \biggr)$$ (where $\omega(n)$ is the number of prime factors of $n$) and show that the latter sum converges as $x\to\infty$ (subhint: it's a familiar sum).

Comment: It makes no big difference whether $1$ belongs to the set , and although $1$ technically satisfies the condition, it makes sense to omit it.

Answer (score 1):

Some hopefully useful information and heuristic ideas here, followed by empirical conclusions. Note that I'm writing on the assumption that you're actually interested specifically in semiprimes (i.e., primes with exactly two distinct prime factors). Including all squarefree $2k$-almost primes seems a bit odd, as the different layers of $k$-almost primes will surely have different properties.

Edit for clarity: This answer assumes we are working only with semiprimes, or $2$-almost primes. Specifically, the reciprocals are of the set

$$\{n \in \Bbb{N} \mid \omega(n) = \Omega(n) =2\}$$

where $\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $n$, and $\Omega(n)$ is the total number of prime factors of $n$.

---

Landau showed that the number of squarefree semiprimes less than or equal to $n$ is

$$\pi_{ss}(n) \approx \frac{n \log \log n}{\log n}$$

Interestingly, it's a very close parallel to the prime number theorem, and allows us to say that the $n^{\text{th}}$ squarefree semiprime is $s_{s,n} \approx n \log n / \log \log n$, and the probability of $n$ being a squarefree semiprime is $P(\omega(n) = \Omega(n) = 2) \approx \log \log n / \log n$. So we should expect to find about $\log \log n$ times as many semiprimes below $n$ as there are primes below $n$.

Separately, from Mertens's Second Theorem we have:

$$\sum_{p \le n} \frac1p \sim \log \log n + M$$

where $M \approx 0.26$ is the Meissel-Mertens constant. Surely, then, we could expect our desired sum to be, say, the above times another factor of $\log \log n$? Well... not so fast. First we should note that while there might be many more semiprimes than primes below $n$, the sum of the prime reciprocals gets a *really* nice headstart. After all, the first three prime reciprocals sum to just over $1$, but the first three semiprime reciprocals sum to not quite $\frac13$. The sum of semiprime reciprocals doesn't overtake the sum of prime reciprocals until around $n=80000$.

So, while $\log \log n <1$ up to $n=15$, our multiplier needs to grow a bit more slowly--something close to $1$ at $n=80000$ or so. If we decide to look *empirically* at the data, it grows about halfway between $\log \log n$ and $\log \log \log n$. If we let a curve fitter take on the data, we find that the multiplier we need is very close to:

$$\gamma \log \log \sqrt{n}$$

where $\gamma \approx 0.5772157$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant, which happens to appear in Mertens's Second Theorem. (Frankly, when you're discussing something related to the primes, and the curve-fitting software spits out $\approx 0.5780$ with no tweaking, what are the chances that's just $\gamma$ hiding in the details? I'm gonna say high enough.)

So: *empirically*, looking only below $10^9$ so far, your sum seems to be within a hair of:

$$\sum_{k \le n}^{\omega(k) = \Omega(k)=2} \frac1k \approx \left(\log \log n + M \right)\left(\gamma \log \log \sqrt{n} \right) + O(1)$$

Note that both approximations take a while to get close to the correct values; these approximations are at best inaccurate below $n=100$, and are at best "good" below $n=10000$.

---

Note also, of course, this is not a proven result; possibly someone with better understanding of number theory can get you that. This is entirely empirical, but it comes close enough (and makes enough sense) that I'm willing to call it, at least, useful.

Comment: Nice answer (+1). Nevertheless a question : Which of the numbers in the sum  are considered by this heuristic ? The semiprimes ? Note that the numbers of the form , say , $2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 11\cdot p$ with some prime $p>11$ are also in the sum, and the sum of the reciprocals of them still diverges. This seems to make no big difference upto $10^9$ , but what if $n$ gets really huge ?

Comment: The question seems to assume the definition $\sum\limits_{n=1}^x \mu(n)^2 \left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{n} & (\Omega(n) \bmod 2)=0 \\
 0 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right.\right)$, and your answer seems assume the definition $\sum\limits_{n=1}^x \mu(n)^2 \left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{n} & \Omega(n)=2 \\
 0 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right.\right)$ where $\Omega(n)$ is the number of primes dividing $n$. Could you please clarify if this is correct?

Comment: Huh, I thought I had written something in about that at the beginning. Yes, I'm assuming semiprimes only. Edit: OK, it looks like I *did* state that at the beginning.

Comment: I should have tagged @StevenClark in that response, sorry. Yes, my answer assumes we're examining only values where $\omega(n) = \Omega(n)=2$. It seems weird to examine the $2k$-almost primes as a set. We should consider either all of the squarefree numbers (addressed by someone above as $\sim 6 \log x / \pi^2$), or only a single class of them, like the semiprimes.

Comment: @EricSnyder Thanks, you did write something at the beginning, but I was having a hard time convincing myself I really understood what you were saying, so I sought clarification via a confirmation of precise formulas.